# Is it possible to source a `.env` file to create Kubernetes secrets?

Tags: kubernetes

The [docs states](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret) that

> To create a Secret from one or more files, use --from-file. You
>   specify files in any plaintext format, such as .txt or .env, as long
>   as the files contain key-value pairs.

*.test-secret*

```
NAME=martin
GENDER=male
```

**Testing to create a secret based on my .test-secret file.**

```
kubectl create secret generic person --from-file .test-secret -o yml

$ kubectl get secret person -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  .test-secret: TkFNRT1tYXJ0aW4KR0VOREVSPW1hbGUK
kind: Secret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2018-07-19T09:23:05Z
  name: person
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "229992"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/secrets/person
  uid: 579198ab-8b35-11e8-8895-42010a840008
type: Opaque
```

Is it possible to read a list of key / values like that? Is it even possible to do so from an `.env` file? `kubectl get pods` returns *CreateContainerConfigError*

**my-app.yml**

```
 77             - name: NAME
 78               valueFrom:
 79                 secretKeyRef:
 80                   name: person
 81                   key: NAME
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, use the option --from-env-file

```
kubectl create secret generic person --from-env-file=.test-secret
```

To consume the secrets from the initial .env file in a pod, you can use the following :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: some-meta
spec:
  containers:
  - name: xyz
    image: abc
    envFrom:
    - secretRef:
        name: person # <--
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do what the OP wanted. The cloud.google.com doc seems to be incorrect in saying `--from-file` should be used, I posted feedback on their page.

Comment: `--from-env-file` is a life-saver :)

Comment: and it seems google quickly updated the documentation. happy to see feedbacks are not ignored

Comment: The `--from-env-file` option has extremely crude parsing, for example if your .env file contains quotes or inline comments, they will be part of your values.

This one-liner can help:

`kubectl create secret generic person --from-env-file=<(env -i sh -c "set -a; . .test-secret; printenv | grep -v '^PWD='")`

Comment: Great answer, please note: the `name: person` should be with double spaces in the beginning, and not with one. yamls are making me vomit.

Comment: Unfortunately, the parser doesn't come even close to following typical [dotenv syntax](https://hexdocs.pm/dotenvy/dotenv-file-format.html).  It doesn't honor quotes, exports, substitution, or multiline.  Still somewhat useful, but definitely some gotchas

Comment: If you use single quotes in .env files to wrap variables values like `FOO='bar'`, this will eliminate them: `cat .test-secret | grep -E '^(.+)=(.+)$' | sed -e "s/='/=/g" | sed -e "s/'$//g"`. I used this to pre-process my .env files before running the `kubectl create secret ... --from-env-file` command.